# Anime about a girl who goes to a hero school without any apparent powers

Tags: story-identification, anime

So I watched this series over 5 years ago and can only remember some specific details

There is a female MC who goes to a hero school without apparent powers leaving her hometown. Initially she faces a lot of opposition from a kid who has a superpower associated with fire. Her powers lie dormant until her friends are at stake. I also remember that earrings had something to do with the powers that the characters wield.

Comment: You could improve this question by going through the checklists [here](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/11874/how-to-ask-a-good-anime-story-id-question) and editing in any relevant info you can think to add.

Answer (score 2):

I was searching as well and I think it is called [*Gakuen Alice*](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt1914829/) (2004).

> Best friends Mikan and Hotaru are separated when Hotaru is scouted by a special school called "Alice Academy." Mikan determines to enroll too but Alice Academy is a mysterious place.

Comment: Hi, welcome to SF&F!  Can you confirm any of the other details in the question, like an antagonist with fire powers or significant earrings?